# can i use bootstrap 3.2 tabs and pills if i am useing bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap 4 version can i use the tabs of  3.2 version of bootstrap in it ?

i have included cdn of `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: no... you have to fit all  your nav to bootstrap 4 classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**... you have to fit all your nav to bootstrap 4 classes 
Here is **diffrence between** `version`:
https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/differences_between_bootstrap_3_and_bootstrap_4.cfm

**Here is example:**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#">Details</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#">Register </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: tell me if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

No, the markup won't be the same. It may work coincidentally but I haven't tried.

But here are the official Pill markup docs from the Bootstrap website:
v4.1: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#pills
v3.3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-pills